# Which plugin to use for calculating edge clustering coefficient in cytoscape

Tags: bioinformatics, cytoscape

I am working on a PPIN where I need to find edge cluster coefficient (ecc)values for unique proteins present in the cluster. I am using cytoscape for generating the value like between centrality, closeness centrality etc. But not able to calculate the ecc. Please help me with the plugin to be installed for my desired calculation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not getting what you want from the built-in Tools > Network Analyzer feature, then I'd recommend trying the Centiscape app: 
http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/centiscape

There may be other apps of interest tagged for "graph analysis":
http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/with_tag/graphanalysis